# Unexpected recursion when enumerator (like Table) uses variable also non-atomically in value list

Tags: evaluation, warning-messages, table

Consider expression

```
Table[k, {k, {a, b, k}}]
```

which correctly evaluates to `{a,b,k}`. The duplication of the enumerated variable `k` as a symbol in the list of successive values has only confused the Mathematica front-end a little, which confounds them in the syntax highlighting:

> [image]

But let's now replace `a`, `b`, `k` with non-atomic expressions like `f[a]`, `f[b]`, `f[k]`.
Alas, evaluating

```
Table[k, {k, {f[a], f[b], f[k]}}]
```

now causes a recursion, and we fail with error

```
$RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of f[k].
```

yielding output

```
{f[a], f[b], Hold[f[k]]}
```

While it surprises me that atomic and non-atomic expressions containing `k` are handled differently (due to the *deferring* of the evaluation of the substituted values), this error is inoffensive enough. It *does* seem like an improper use of `Table` at first glance.

But now, consider a natural consequence of this issue. We define

```
func[objs_] :=
    Table[k, {k, objs}]
```

where we cannot be blamed for the intuitive treatment of `k` as a "private variable", in a sense. As before, if global `k` is given atomically to `func`, it behaves as expected:

```
func[{a,b,k}]

>>> {a,b,k}
```

But non-atomic expressions containing global `k` give a very astonishing error to the caller:

```
func[{f[a], f[b], f[k]}]

>>> $RecursionLimit
```

I'm hesitant to call this a bug because of all the nuances of Mathematica's evaluation order. But from the user perspective, this is *bizarre* and suggests great diligance is required to ensure global symbols are never passed to expressions which contain colliding enumerated variables.

In my situation, I can of course <strike>avoid</strike> reduce the chance of the trouble with something hideous like:

```
func[objs_] :=
    Table[Private`func`k, {Private`func`k, objs}]
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is this issue avoidable, or is this a bug? I'm using v13.0.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64 bit).

Comment: You could use `$k` instead of `Private`func`k`. That's a pretty standard usage of the `$` "prefix". That said, I *think* `Table` is like the `Block` scoping construct, in that it doesn't create a new internal variable and instead uses the same symbol `k`, leading to these kinds of issues.  (That's why `k = 2; Table[k, {k, 1, 2}]` still yields `{1, 2}`.) In contrast, `Module` makes new internal variables: `Module[{k}, k]` yields something like `k$372262`, so you could wrap the right-hand side in a `Module`. Or, keep track of variables, try not to overload them, and avoid globally-defined ones.

Comment: (1) `Table[k,{k,{f[j],f[k]}}]` has to set (as in the function `Set`) the iterator variable `k` to `f[k]`. So that's an obvious infinite recursion. So we get `{f[j], TerminatedEvaluation["RecursionLimit"]}`. (2) `Table` does use `Block`-type scoping; this is documented for how iterators get scoped. One implication is that the iterator variable `k` will be indistinguishable from the element inside the expression `f[k]`. Which is fortunate since that's needed behavior in many ways. For example, consider nested iterators where a bound in one depends on a value in another.